# Apache 2, PHP - Problem on HTTP GET domain

Tags: php, apache2

When I've loaded my website, I noticed all the GET messages use as a domain the host IP address instead fo the hostname url which creates a certificate problem.

my website is hosted on ubuntu machine and used apache2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy4NX.jpg)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Apache config, then something like this should do it :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```